# How do I conditionally delete strings from an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I need to remove any strings from an array that are not of a certain length. The assignment recommends using `map` or `map!`. I have been playing with `map!`, `delete_if`, and `keep_if`, but I am getting nowhere. Can anyone help me? Below is one of my attempts:

```
dictionary = Array.new

file = File.open("words.txt").each do | line |
    dictionary.push line
end

(wordlength = gets)
wordlength = wordlength.to_i

dictionary = dictionary.reject {|word| word.length != wordlength }

puts dictionary
```

Comment: `word` is an *item* rather than an *iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove whitespaces from your input:

```
dictionary.push line.strip
```

By the way, the code for reading your file can be simplified:

```
dictionary = File.readlines("words.txt").map { |line| line.strip }
```

(As for the original question, both `delete_if` and `reject`/`reject!` work)

**EDIT**

The complete code could be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

dictionary = File.readlines("words.txt").map { |line| line.strip }
wordlength = gets.to_i
dictionary.delete_if { |word| word.length != wordlength }
puts dictionary #test
```

Keep in mind that `reject!` and `delete_if` change the original array, so if you want to keep the original values you should use

```
new_dictionary = dictionary.reject { |word| word.length != wordlength }
```

or even

```
new_dictionary = dictionary.select {|word| word.length == wordlength }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This was uberhelpful

Answer (score 2):

You should need to use [`Array#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if).

```
dictionary.delete_if{|s| s.size != wordlength }
```

Comment: didn't work. I will post my complete code. Maybe I've done something dumb elsewhere

Comment: Thanks. I went with keep_if because it made more logical sense to me, but your syntax helped me get there.

Comment: @user1628498 As you asked how to delete,,so i took this method.. But it is ok,, that you got the point.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `#reject` here.

```
dictionary = ["apple", "bug", "cup", "drain"]
dictionary.reject {|word| word.length != 3}
```

Comment: didn't work. I will post my complete code. Maybe I've done something dumb elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

`|word|` here is different from `i` as you would use in C++. `i` would be referring to the index of the object in `dictionary`. `|word|` here refers directly to the object in the `dictionary` array. e.g.

```
dictionary = ["animal", "animate"]
```

`|word|` would refer to the object `"animal"`, `i` would refer to index `0` of `dictionary`. To make it clearer, Ruby even has a enumerable method:

```
.each_with_index do |element, index|
end
```

where `|element|` refers to the object, and `|index|` refers to the index of the object.

I don't recommend deleting through the very array that you're iterating through, it comes out with quirky results since the size of your array changes each time you delete an element.

Arup's suggestion of using `delete_if` should work fine. If that doesn't work, you can try another method (albeit less efficient) by setting each `|word|` equal to `nil` if it's length `!= wordlength`, then compacting it (removing objects that are equal to `nil`).

```
dictionary = []

file = File.open("words.txt").each do | line |
    dictionary << line.strip #strip removes whitespaces and newlines
end

wordlength = gets.chomp.to_i #chomp removes any newlines "\n" 

dictionary = dictionary.each do |word|
    word = nil if word.length != wordlength
end

puts dictionary.compact!
```

Comment: This was exactly the kind of clarification I needed. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

dictionary = File.open("words.txt").map do |line|
  line.strip # remove line end and whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the line
end

wordlength = gets
wordlength = wordlength.to_i

dictionary = dictionary.reject { |word| word.length != wordlength }

puts dictionary #test
```

Some comments as it is your first ruby program ever:

1. It's more common in ruby to add items to an array using *<<* operator.
2. You can use *map* method to transform each item in an array into something else and return an array of the transformed items.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `delete_if` or `keep_if` I'd just group the words by length:

```
file = "/usr/share/dict/words"
words = File.readlines(file).map { |line| line.chomp }.group_by(&:length)
```

This makes it trivial to retrieve words with different lengths:

```
words[5] # all words with length 5
#=> ["aalii", "Aaron", "abaca", "aback", "abaff", "abaft", "Abama", "abase", "abash", "abask", ...]

words[10] # all words with length 10
#=> ["abalienate", "abaptiston", "abasedness", "abbeystede", "abbreviate", "abdication", "abdicative", "abdominous", "aberdevine", "Aberdonian", ...]
```